# How do I find a Service by task name in Windows?

Tags: services, tasks

E.g. I know the service uses 'myservice.exe'. How do I find what's the registered service name using this task, from MS-DOS prompt or Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I find a Service by task name

Use `wmic service` together with `findstr`.

Example:

```
C:\Users\David>wmic service get DisplayName, PathName | findstr httpd.exe
wampapache64                                                            "c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Findstr - Search for strings - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [WMIC - Windows Management - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)